# Angular: ng-repeat does not update on view after removing the element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ng-repeat` to show the list of items in `view`.
In my `controller` the array is updating but the view does not update.
 I don't know where I am doing mistake.

Can someone help me to resolve it?

Here is my view part:

```
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in closedBoards track by $index">
      <a href="#" data-ng-if="(item.closeBoard)"><span class="board-span" tooltip-html-unsafe="<strong>Board Name: {{item.name}}<br />Created by: {{item.createdBy.name}}<br />Created At: {{item.createdAt}}</strong> " tooltip-placement="top"><strong>{{item.name}}</strong><span><img class="reopen-board" src="../images/reopen.png" open-board data-ng-click="show(item._id)"></span></span></a>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

And this is my controller code

```
$scope.reOpenBoard = function() {
            BoardFactory.openBoard(boardId).then(function(data) {
                    $scope.closedBoards.some(function(closed,index){
                        if(closed._id==boardId){
                        $scope.closedBoards.splice(index,1);

                            return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                    });
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err); 
            })
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try by returning ``$scope.closedBoards`` instead of ``return true``

Comment: @SameerK that will not work, becouse it's `some method` property.

Comment: The code is fine. Normally it would update view in this case. I guess there is something else you are not showing. I recommend to create a simple demo in plunrk, otherwise unlikely someone will guess and help you.

Comment: @dfsq this code is depended to other code  and it's hard to write there so that I didn't give any plunker link

Comment: Sure, this is always the case. What you need to do is to try to isolate the issue. Likely you will find the problem yourself while doing it. Otherwise, you are posing *working* (although a little clumsy) code.

Answer (score 0):

If `$scope.closedBoards` is a jQuery plugin container and `.some` is a plugin function, you should use $scope.$apply wrapper around your AngularCode:

```
$scope.reOpenBoard = function() {
            BoardFactory.openBoard(boardId).then(function(data) {
                    $scope.closedBoards.some(function(closed,index){                                
                            if(closed._id==boardId){
                                $scope.$apply(function(){
                                    $scope.closedBoards.splice(index,1);
                                });
                                return true;
                            }else{
                                return false;
                            }

                    });
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err); 
            })
        }
```

But i think you have a mistake in your code. $scope.closedBoards - must be an array of data, and it can't contains methods like `.some`

Comment: Check this [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: Nice o_O I have fixed example a little, try $scope.$apply

Comment: @steppefox I am getting the error something like this `digist already is in progress`